# Passing JS code from a file as a string into a function

Tags: javascript, object

I have a file with a JS object like this:

```
{
    function1: function(arg){
        return arg + 1
    },
    
    function2: function(arg){
        return arg * 2
    }
}
```

I want to pass this object (as type string), to a function that takes another JS object where the value of one of the keys should be the mentioned object, like this:

```
const myArg = {data: myData, functions: <THE_OBJECT_MENTIONED_ABOVE>}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why would you pass it as string and not keep it as-is?

Comment: Deserialization of code from strings is a huge security risk, which is why the built-in `JSON.parse()` method doesn't support such an arrangement. This question would benefit greatly from a succinct explanation of the requirement that's giving rise to such a design.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm using a (trusted) 3rd party library that allows to pass the functions I want to perform in some cases as an object of casted as string, this is the reason. All the information can be found here: https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/ns-debug#debug_tracetransaction in the section `JavaScript-based tracing`.

Comment: @esqew that and JSON doesn’t have functions

Comment: @evolutionxbox I suppose the spec is also contributing to that, yes. Great point!